# make directory structure for each row within the text file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have my `Git` branch cloned into `/apps/git/mygitbranch`

I have a shell script which creates branch.diff, giving me difference between master and my branch as follows:

```
Database/demo.sql
Database/demo2.sql
Java/Packages/test.java
```

I need to write another shell script to read each row from above file and copy only the mentioned differences from `mygitbranch` into another location on the server:

```
/apps/deploy/Database
```

and insert `demo.sql` and `demo2.sql` in it.

Similarly,

```
/apps/deploy/Java/Packages/test.java
```

Please help.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Don't know how to start. I wrote the shell to clone the branch into my server and give me the diff. But the cloned branch has all the code. I need to deploy only difference. If you could give me some hints, I can work and get back

Comment: Steps are: In shell script (1) Read `branch.diff` file line by line. Each line has filenames (2) Use `cp` command to copy file from source dir to destination dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

while read -r line
   do
   src="${currDir}/${repository_name}-${branch}/$line"
   cp -R $src $deploy_loc
done < "$branch.diff"

It reads the branch.diff line by line and copies the files from src to deployloc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
cat branch.diff | while IFS= read -r file; do
  cp --  "$file" to/where/you/want/your/file/copied/to/
done
```

Does it help you?

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I found an answer 

Comment: in case my answer above is correct, then you could accept it? And/or maybe add your own?